# Edit the BCS search item

Tags: search, bcs

I have created an external list and external content type using SharePoint Designer. I need to search an item in the external list. So I configured search in central admin. I am able to search an item in the external list. But the search items are read only. Could you please suggest me how to edit the items.

Comment: When you configured the external content type and list did you ensure that you had the Update and Create operations enabled? ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee558778.aspx

Comment: yes I have create,Read Item,Update, Delete,Read List operations. I am able to edit the item from the external list.I configured search to search an item in the external list.From the search results page I am unable to edit the search results.

Comment: From the search results page do you get a link to the display form for the item? Or are you trying to edit IN the search results?